# Raycast hit position doesn't not change when the parent object not moving on the z axis

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm raycasting from a face to a plane a. when reading the hit position I noticed that it doesn't update correctly when moving objects. it only updates when the object is moving in the z-axis (the parent object or the plane).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Hit Position' is returned in the Object Space of the modified object.

So long as the target plane is parallel to the relative movement of the modified object, then, measured along the modified object's ****own**** axes,  the coordinate of the hit-point will be constant.

If the plane is tilted with respect to the movement, that's a different story.